# Parameters required for Scipy Spectrogram

Tags: python, scipy, spectrogram

Given a 40 Hz non-stationary signal, with a total of 4800 samples, I want to generate a spectrogram with appropriate parameters, and I was wondering how best to set the parameters in `scipy.signal.spectrogram` to use a window of 5 seconds and a 2.5 second overlap.

Would the following be correct?

```
f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(trace.data, fs=40, nperseg=200, window=('hamming'), noverlap=100)
```

I get slightly confused if I use a different windowing technique, i.e. `slepian`, which requires a width.  What is the difference between this width used with the `slepian` window, and the `nperseg` parameter?  Also, what would be the benefit of applying zero-padding (`nfft`)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameterization seems correct, assuming that with *a 40 Hz signal* you mean a signal recorded at a rate of 40 samples per second.

The effect of zero padding with `nfft` is making the spectrum smoother and it can help improve computational performance by bringing the FFT length to a good value (multiples of small primes, like e.g. powers of 2 usually work well).

The difference between window width and `nperseg` is that the width determines the shape of the window and `nperseg` is how many samples the window contains. You could, for example, have a window with many samples but if most of them are close to zero the *effective window length* is shorter.

I guess this is best illustrated using an image:

[image]

With the same number of samples you can have a wider or narrower window, while the number of samples basically only detrmines how finely the window shape is resolved.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import windows as wnd

i = 0
for n in [10, 20]:
    for width in [0.2, 0.9]:
        i += 1
        plt.subplot(2, 2, i)
        plt.stem(wnd.slepian(n, width))

        plt.title('n={}, width={}'.format(n, width))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your description and corresponding image.  My understanding of both the window width and numbers per segment is significantly improved.  Cheers.